# WCAG 2.0 issue in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, wcag2.0

I am using tawdis online tool to validate **WCAG 2.0 AA Level compatibility**. I am facing an error

> "Web page well-formedness"

, when I use below code. How to fix this error in WCAG validation ?

```
<iframe title="brady-flanary video1" width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T4isjKuMdQA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by removing `allowfullscreen` attribute from the <iframe>

```
<iframe title="brady-flanary video1" width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T4isjKuMdQA" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```